# Separate Cell Styles -- Possibility

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Is it possible to give separate cell styles in a table view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look at pretty much any of the Apple apps. They tend to use tables of different controls for their settings. That's why the table cells have different reuse identifiers. That way you get dequeue the correct type and change properties.

Comment: Can we set the Separator style also at cell level?

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could create your own table cell subclass and put a separator in that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. That's why you set cell the style to the cell itself, not the table view.

Comment: Can we set the Separator style also at cell level? I need different separation styles for different cells.